# Improving the speed of the HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

Just coded my own realisation of HashMap with open addressing, key type is int and value type is long. But it works more slowly than exicted java realisation even when i just add a new values. Whats way to make it faster?

```
public class MyHashMap {
private int maxPutedId =0;
private int size;
private int[] keys;
private long[] values;
private  boolean[] change;
public MyHashMap(int size){
    this.size = size;
    keys = new int[size];
    values = new long[size];
    change = new boolean[size];
}
public MyHashMap(){
    this.size = 100000;
    keys = new int[size];
    values = new long[size];
    change = new boolean[size];
}
public boolean put(int key, long value){
    int k = 0;
    boolean search = true;
    for(int i = 0;i<maxPutedId+2;i++){
        if(search&& !change[i] && keys[i] == 0 && values [i] == 0 ){
            k=i;
            search = false;
        }
        if(change[i] && keys[i] == key ){
            return false;
        }
    }
    keys[k] = key;
    values[k] = value;
    change[k] = true;
    maxPutedId = k;
    return true;
}
public Long get(int key) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (change[i] && keys[i] == key) {
            return values[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
    public int size(){
    int s = 0;
    for(boolean x: change){
        if(x) s++;
    }
    return s;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not implemented a hash table; there is no hashing going on. For example, your get() method is doing a linear traversal through the key array. A hash table implementation is supposed to be able to compute the array entry where the key is most likely to be found (and will in fact be found if it exists and there were no hash collisions).

A simple hash table would look like this: we first compute a hash from the key. Then we look at that slot in the table. Ideally, that's where the key will be found.  However, if the key is not there, it could be due to collisions, so then we scan (assuming open addressing) looking for the key in subsequent slots - until we've looked through the whole table or found an unoccupied slot.

I wrote 'get' since it seemed simpler :-)

This is 'off the top of my head' code so you will need to check it carefully.

```
Long get(int key) {
    int h = hash(key);

    // look in principal location for this key
    if (change[h] && keys[h] == key)
        return values[h];

    // nope, scan table (wrapping around at the end)
    // and stop when we have found the key, scanned
    // the whole table, or met an empty slot
    int h0 = h; // save original position
    while ((h = (h+1) % size) != h0 && change[h])
        if ( keys[h] == key)
            return values[h];

    return null;
}
```

I probably should have written 'put' first to be more instructive.

The hash function, for `int` keys, could be computed as `key % size`.  Whether that's a good hash depends on the distribution of your keys; you want a hash that avoids collisions.

Comment: I dont understand why this should work. size is 1000. If first key I put is 125(keys[0] is 125) with some value. Your method will start searching from keys[125] and following, and will never find the disired one

Comment: I only wrote ```get```. You need to write a similar ```put```.  If hash(125) equals 125, then your ```put(125, value)``` will insert the entry at keys[125], assuming that keys[125] was empty.  That is the essence of a hash table -- the hash function indicates where the entry should go. That's why it's faster than a simple array; absent collisions, insertion and lookup are O(1) rather than O(n).

Comment: Thanks, I finally understood.